# MySQL Prepare Statement Equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have been migrating MySQL SP to SQL Server. 
MySQL has [prepare statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), Which supports assigning comples SQL query as string and executing it later.

```
SET @msquery="select * from tblEmployee" <<More complex queries here>>
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @msquery;
          EXECUTE stmt3;
          DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
```

Do we have an equivalent in SQL server?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175528%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server too you can do this like

```
SET @msquery='select * from tblEmployee' --<<More complex queries here>>
EXECUTE sp_executesql @msquery
```

Note: here @msquery should be of type ntext/nchar/nvarchar, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

More Complex queries needs further study. May be below link will help you further.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

In case, I am missing something or any further assistance is required please let me know.

Comment: Just saying `EXECUTE (@msquery)` is fine.

Comment: Yes, just EXECUTE or EXEC is also fine but sp_executesql is better in terms of performance & security.
Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/18/exec-vs-sp-executesql.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has the [sp_prepare](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848808.aspx) system stored procedure.